# PostgreSQL Data Selection

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to write PostgreSQL code that looks at the sample data in the selects only the persons who have been active for the whole first quarter( 01/01/2018 to 03/31/2018) as shown in the desired output? Note that person H should not be selected because they are missing January.

Sample Data

```
    Person  Start Date  End Date
    A       1/1/2018    1/31/2018
    A       2/1/2018    2/28/2018
    A       3/1/2018    3/31/2018
    B       1/1/2018    2/28/2018
    C       1/1/2018    2/28/2018
    C       3/1/2018    3/31/2018
    D       2/1/2018    3/31/2018
    E       2/1/2018    2/28/2018
    F       1/1/2018    3/31/2018
    G       1/1/2018    4/30/2018
    H       2/1/2018    4/30/2018
```

Desired Output

```
    Person
    A
    C
    F
    G
```

Comment: Please edit the question and paste the example data and expected output as text, remove images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your columns are proper DATE columns and there are no overlaps, you could do something like this:

```
select person
from the_table
group by person
having sum(end_date - start_date + 1) >= date '2018-03-31' - date '2018-01-01' + 1
order by person;
```

Subtracting one `date` from another yields the number of days between those two dates. Then the sum of all differences is compared to the difference between the start and end date of the quarter.

Online example: https://rextester.com/OIN10602

Comment: Hi, I added a follow up question to this. Would you be able to take a look please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805289/follow-up-question-postgresql-data-selection